# Defining DataFrame indexes through dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am setting up an empty DataFrame which I want to populate later. I am providing a list as indexes and want to give it a name, since I want to push the df to a db later. I know I could just change the name with `df.index.name` so acutally solving that task is not the question here. My intuition to solve this problem was to just provide the index as a dictionary with the name as key and the list of indexes as values. I'll provide an example to clarify my confusion:

```python
import pandas as pd

COLS = ['Name','Date']
IDX_ARR = [0,1,3,4,5]
IDX = {'Id':IDX_ARR}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=COLS,
                  index=IDX_ARR)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=COLS,
                  index=IDX)

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

As a response I get:

```
  Name Date
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN

   Name Date
Id  NaN  NaN
```

While `df1` correctly shows all indexes, it doesn't (obviously - since I didn't define anything) show the title of the indexes - so far so expected.
Looking at `df2` it does correctly display the title of the index, but does NOT display the indexes. **Why? And how to do it?**

My expected result would be:

```
  Name Date
Id
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN
```

P.S. Again, I know I could just call `df1.index.name = 'Id'`, but is there not a way to do this in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "**Why?**"

Simply because pandas does not support setting the index name when initializing a dataframe with an index array.

For the "**How to do it?**"

you can create a pandas Index object from the `IDX` dictionary and use it to initialize the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

COLS = ['Name','Date']
IDX_ARR = [0,1,3,4,5]
IDX = {'Id': IDX_ARR}

index_key = list(IDX.keys())[0]
index_values = IDX[index_key]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=COLS, index=pd.Index(data = index_values, name = index_key))

print(df2)
```

Comment: Thank you! That explains it well.